# Xdebug connected to debugging client, but not working

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, xdebug

Xdebug logs are saying that he is able to connect to PhpStorm, but PhpStorm cant run the debug process.

```
[23] Log opened at 2023-01-11 21:16:29.141347
[23] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[23] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[23] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///legacy/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.1.7" protocol_version="1.0" appid="23"><engine version="3.1.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[20] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[20] Log closed at 2023-01-11 21:16:29.451767
```

[image]
[image]

Application is in monorepo in folder `legacy/`, run by docker via 8000 port.

```
PHP 8.1.7 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2022 23:29:02) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: *"Xdebug logs are saying that he is able to connect to PhpStorm, but PhpStorm cant run the debug process."* Sorry but very unlikely. That's not a response from PhpStorm. Way too short. **1)** Please show your LIVE Xdebug settings (get `xdebug_info()` output captured in the same way as you are trying to debug -- a CLI or a web page). the `host.docker.internal:9003` seems fine .. but it's better to check other stuff as well.

Comment: **2)** Please check what process listens on TCP 9003 port. According to your screenshots it supposed to be PhpStorm .. but you are on Mac ... and it may not detect that the port is already in use. Please use something like `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` and see what process that would be. Maybe you are forwarding it to another container by mistake or something.

Comment: The reason I'm saying this -- Xdebug log that you have provided shows a typical response of **php-fpm** when Xdebug connects to that by mistake (usually happens with 9000 port that Xdebug v2 and php-fpm use by default).

Comment: BTW -- if you do not use Xdebug v2 at all, change Xdebug port in PhpStorm settings from default `9000, 90003` to just `9003` (it's a per project setting anyway). For CLI scripts PhpStorm uses first port in the list...

Comment: @LazyOne you are the best! Your comment about checking what listens to a 9003 port fixes the problem :) I was exposing the port in a docker, so PhpStorm was not able to connect to it.

Comment: The log is suspect, as it shows both `[20]` and `[23]` in the margin, which indicates they are from two different PIDs.